# Jquery Cycle and Pixastic fast blur

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-cycle, pixastic

I am trying to cycle my image and blur the background image but the problem is it only blurs the first image but not the next image.

```
<div id="banner_images">        
    <div id="banner_cycle_wrapper">
        <div id="banner_bg_cycle">
            <img src="source.png" class="blur">
        </div>
        <div id="banner_cycle_container">
            <img src="source.png">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="banner_cycle_wrapper" >
        <div id="banner_bg_cycle">
            <img alt="" src="source.png" class="blur">
        </div>
        <div id="banner_cycle_container">
            <img src="source.png">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
$('#banner_images').cycle({
    fx: 'fade',
    timeout: 2000
});

$(".blur").pixastic("blurfast", {amount:0.5});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing CLASS to add in that

```
 class="blur"
```

this should be added to each image you want to have the same effect.

Updated Code:

```
<div id="banner_images"> 
   <div id="banner_cycle_wrapper"> 
      <div id="banner_bg_cycle"> 
         <img alt="" src="source.png"/> 
      </div> 
      <div id="banner_cycle_container"> 
         <img alt="" src="img1.png" class="blur" /> 
         <img alt="" src="img2.png" class="blur" /> 
      </div> 
   </div> 
 </div>
```

I hope this will help :)

Comment: Sorry that was a typo error. even with class="blur" on both image it only blur 1 image